# How to Stop OneNote API From Returning ID for Deleted Pages

Tags: python, delete-file, onenote, http-delete, onenote-api

I place a call using the OneNote REST API to return a list of all the pages in a section. This works successfully. However, some of the pages it returns should no longer exist! Yet I can see their information, IDs, etc., even though they have previously been deleted. But if I try to delete them again using REST, I get the error:

```
ERROR (deleteFromURL):  <Response [404]>
{
    "error":{
      "code":"20102","message":"The specified resource ID does not exist.","@api.url":"http://aka.ms/onenote-errors#C20102"
    }
}
```

How come OneNote keeps returning pages that no longer exist (even after many days), and how do I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This option is no longer available.

---

I assume these pages do appear as deleted in your notebook if you open OneNote.
Can you try adding this header to your GET ~/pages request?

```
FavorDataRecency: true
```

This will bypass our index and go directly to your pages. It will take longer but should be consistent - do you see your pages when you do that?

Additionally, to better investigate this on our end, can you provide us with
- The value of the X-CorrelationId header of your API request to GET pages (the one without the FavorDataRecency header)
- One of the id's of your deleted pages

Comment: Doing that seemed to fix the problem of getting pages that no longer existed! :)