# OneNote API: get list of Pages from Section, filtering out the deleted pages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

When I use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/<id>/pages
```

either from IOS SDK, Android SDK or even demo Graph Explorer 
the result will contain pages that are deleted.

**Is there a way to specify request params to return only pages that are in the "not deleted" state?**

e.g. maybe by using some undocumented query filters

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters

---------- EDIT --------------------------------

I've tried using `FavorDataRecency: true` header but still getting deleted items

[How to Stop OneNote API From Returning ID for Deleted Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621322/how-to-stop-onenote-api-from-returning-id-for-deleted-pages)

same for /sections endpoint (deleted sections are being returned)

This makes the whole OneNote API unusable :( as there is no way to distinguish between deleted and active notes. A simple flag `isActive` would solve all this.

Related links

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/390

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/33970093-bug-rest-api-getting-page-collection-of-a-secti

for debugging,
these are the response headers for the requests from Graph Explorer:

`client-request-id: 4363c28a-98af-4ea4-892c-00fb0f437bd3`

`request-id: 4363c28a-98af-4ea4-892c-00fb0f437bd3`